# Multiple RewriteRule not working from .htaccess and giving a 404 page not found error but why?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite some url's with .htaccess. At first I added one rewrite rule and it worked perfectly but few days later I added another one but it's not working. It is giving a 404 server error.

Here is my .htaccess code

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rewrite Url / It's the first one and it's working
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /details.php?post=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)$ /details.php?post=$1 [QSA,L]
    
    # Rewrite Url / It's the 2nd one and it's not working
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^hospital/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /hospital-profile.php?v=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^hospital/([^/.]+)$ /hospital-profile.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My question is, why my 2nd rule notworking? I am searching for 3 days on google + stackoverflow but no luck!

Comment: Did you find anything? i am facing the same problem in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351735/htaccess-second-rewriterule-not-work-and-gives-404-page-not-found-error

Comment: no, nothing. :(

Comment: As a result of my research, I finally found a solution. You can take a look at the link I gave, maybe it will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336709/second-rewriterule-is-not-working-in-htaccess-and-shows-404-not-found-page