# Second rewriterule is not working in htaccess and shows 404 not found page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Hi I have links like this:

```
www.example.com/a-letter/a-1.html
www.example.com/b-letter/b-1.html
```

There are 3 files under the a letter and b-letter folder also. And i removed `a-letter` section with this .htaccess code:

```
##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /a-letter/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^a-letter/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
##
```

And removed `b-letter` section with this .htaccess code:

```
##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /b-letter/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^b-letter/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
##
```

I am redirecting all `a-1` `a-2` `a-3` files with this htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?a-letter/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/a-letter%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(a-1|a-2|a-3)/? /a-letter/$1.html [END]
```

Also i am redirecting all `b-1` `b-2` `b-3` files with this htaccess code:

```
##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?b-letter/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/b-letter%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(b-1|b-2|b-3)/? /b-letter/$1.html [END]
##
```

All these codes in the same .htaccess file and when i want to open `www.example.com/a-1.html` page opens correctly . My problem is although I use the same codes for `b-letter`, but I cannot open the link `www.example.com/b-1` . I got 404 not found error. When i replace the codes for b-letter to the top of the .htaccess file this time `www.example.com/b-1` opens correctly but the `www.example.com/a-1` link does not open which ones codes at below in .htaccess file. I tried to change [END] flag to [L] it did not work for me. What can i do in this situation? Is there any way for the disable importance of sorting in .htaccess file . I did a lot of research on stackoverflow and other sites, but I couldn't find any results working for me.  I will be grateful if you could help me. Thanks from now.

**UPDATE:**

I also share my full code of .htaccess file below by request of @anubhava

```
#Redirection http to https start#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#Redirection http to https end#


##301 Redirection Start##
Redirect 301 /index.html https://www.example.com/
Redirect 301 /index https://www.example.com/
##301 Redirection End##

##adding www to links start##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
##adding www to links end##



#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
##

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
##

------------------------------------------------------------------------


# remove a-letter from URLs start#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /a-letter/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^a-letter/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
# remove a-letter from URLs end#

## Rewrite non a-letter links start##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?a-letter/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/a-letter%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(a-1|a-2|a-3|a-4|a-5|a-6|a-7|a-8)/? /a-letter/$1.html [END]
## Rewrite non a-letter links start##

# remove comments/a/ from links start#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} comments/a/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^comments/a/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
# remove comments/a/ from links end#


## Rewrite non comments/a/ links start##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?comments/a/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/a%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.?]+)$/? /comments/a/$1.html [END]
##Rewrite non comments/a/ links end##

------------------------------------------------------------------------


# remove b-letter from URLs start#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /b-letter/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^b-letter/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
# remove b-letter from URLs end#

## Rewrite non b-letter links start##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?b-letter/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/b-letter%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(b-1|b-2|b-3|b-4|b-5|b-6|b-7|b-8)/? /b-letter/$1.html [END]
##Rewrite non b-letter links end##



#remove comments/b/ from links start#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} comments/b/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^comments/b/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
# remove comments/b/ from links end#    

## Rewrite non comments/b/ links start##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?comments/b/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/b%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.?]+)$/? /comments/b/$1.html [END]
## Rewrite non-comments/b/ links end##

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I added full code of my htaccess file. If you have any advice I'd be happy to try. Thank you from now.

Comment: It is very long and I cannot spot any obvious error. Try to test with a smaller code first

Comment: i finally found a solution i used this code for rewriting non comment/a/ links and everything worked `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/b/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.?]+)$/?$ comments/b/$1.html [L,NC]` This was your answer in another question and i modified it a little bit. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I solved my problem like this:

Firstly My website links was like this:

```
www.example.com/a-letter/a-1.html
www.example.com/b-letter/b-1.html
www.example.com/comments/a/word-abc.html
www.example.com/comments/b/word-xyz.html
```

I removed `a-letter` from link directory with this code:

```
# remove /a-letter/ from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /a-letter/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^a-letter/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

and for `b-letter` for `comments/a/` and `comments/b/` like above only letters different.

I changed rewrite rule internally for `/a-1` `/a-2` `/a-3` like this: (Moreover my hosting service use lite speed server because of this reason i wrote `<IfModule LiteSpeed>` intead of `<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>`) with this code [www.example.com/a-1](http://www.example.com/a-1) displays [www.example.com/a-1.html](http://www.example.com/a-1.html) 's content internally. There is no change in the link.

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(a-1|a-2|a-3|a-4|a-5|a-6|a-7|a-8)/? a-letter/$1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also i changed for  `b-letter` and `b-1` `b-2` `b-3` like above only letters different.

I rewrote non `/comments/a/` links internally with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/a/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.?]+)$/?$ comments/a/$1.html [L,NC]
```

and for non `comments/b/` links like above only letters different.

My `.htaccess` file's contents, in order, are as follows:

```
##Redirect http to https start##
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
##Redirect http to https end##



##301 Redirect Start##
Redirect 301 /index.html https://www.example.com/
Redirect 301 /index https://www.example.com/
##301 Redirect End##


##Remove .html extension start##
##example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
##


##301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
##
##Remove .html extension end##
------------------------------------------------------------------------

##remove /a-letter/ from link ##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /a-letter/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^a-letter/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
##
.
.
.

##Rewrite non /a-letter/ links internally start##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(a-1|a-2|a-3|a-4|a-5|a-6|a-7|a-8)/? a-letter/$1.html [L]
</IfModule>
##Rewrite non /a-letter/ links internally end##
.
.
.
 
##remove /comments/a/ from link start##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} comments/a/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^comments/a/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
##remove /comments/a/ from link end##
.
.
.

##Rewrite non /comments/a/ links internally start##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/a/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.?]+)$/?$ comments/a/$1.html [L,NC]
##Rewrite non /comments/a/ links internally end##
.
.
.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Every thing works fine with this codes and my website have full friendly-urls . Special thanks to the `@arkascha` and `@anubhava` for their helps.

Comment: A very good solution ++

Comment: thank you very much @anubhava your helps very contributed me.